# PostgreSQL restoring dump doesnt run

Tags: postgresql, psql, dump

I am trying to add data to newly created DB from .sql file but it doesnt work on my machine(mac) and works for others.
So first i created DB and role for it and then i tried restore it via terminal with this:

```
psql -U username -d dbname < filename.sql
```

Nothing happens in terminal , it doesnt even give error it just gives next/new line.
I tried to do with PGAdmin or Dbeaver to restore but these dont support dump restoring, so i also tried to install jetbrains DataGrip and when i try restore file from there the logs give result of

```
psql process finished
```

The process ends in like 3 seconds but it doesnt fill the DB with anything. I have tried multiple times to  restart psql , delete dband recreate and do the same steps but no result.

Comment: Try without redirecting: `psql -U ..  -d ...  -f filename.sql`

Comment: Try running `psql` with the `-a` and `-e` option and see what gets printed. Compare that with the SQL file to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: What is the size of `filename.sql`?

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find a decent solution, so i deleted DB and reinstalled postgres (v14) on local and used same script. Now its fine.